# Can't Login with OOP PHP (Prepared Statement)

Tags: php, ajax, oop, authentication, prepared-statement

Recently I've been struggling in creating Login System using OOP PHP with Prepared Statement. When I clicked the login button after inputted the correct username and password, it still validate that I inputted the wrong username and password. Here's my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**login.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once 'templates/header.php';
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/login-style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $('#usernameID').val();
        var password = $('#passwordID').val();

        $.post("validation/validation_login.php",{
            user_val : username,
            password_val : password,

        },function(data){
            $('.error-message').html(data);
        });
    });
});

</script>

<title>Login</title>
<form>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" id="usernameID" name="username" 
    placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"> <br>

    <input type="password" id="passwordID" name="password" 
    placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"> <br>

    <input type="button" id="login" name="register-button" value="Login">

</form>

<div class="error-message">

</div>

<?php 
    require_once 'templates/footer.php';
?>
```

**validation_login.php**

```
<?php 

    require_once '../classes/input.php';
    require_once '../classes/session.php';
    require_once '../classes/database.php';

    class validation_login{

        private $username,$password;
        public $errorMessage;

        public function validate_login(){
            $db = new database();
            $this->username = input::get('user_val');
            $this->password = input::get('password_val');

            if(empty($this->username) || empty($this->password)){
                $this->errorMessage = "Please fill all the fields!";
                return false;
            }else if(!$db->login()){
                $this->errorMessage = "Invalid username or password!";
                return false;
            }else{
                session::set('username',$this->username);
                header('Location: index.php');
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    $validate_login = new validation_login();
    $validate_login->validate_login();

    echo "$validate_login->errorMessage";

?>
```

**database.php**

```
<?php 

    class database{

        //db_initialization
        private $HOST = 'localhost',
        $USERNAME = 'root',
        $PASSWORD = '',
        $DBNAME = 'auth',
        $connect;

        //db_insert
        private $usernameInput,
        $firstnameInput,
        $lastnameInput,
        $passwordInput,
        $hashedPassword;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->connect = new mysqli($this->HOST,$this->USERNAME,   
            $this->PASSWORD,$this->DBNAME) or die('connection error');
        }

        public function insert_data(){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users 
            (username,first_name,last_name,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            if($statement = $this->connect->prepare($sql)){
                $this->usernameInput = input::get('user_val');
                $this->firstnameInput = input::get('first_name_val');
                $this->lastnameInput = input::get('last_name_val');
                $this->passwordInput = input::get('password_val');
                $this->hashedPassword = password_hash( $this->passwordInput,                 
                PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $statement->bind_param("ssss",$this->usernameInput,    
                $this- >firstnameInput,$this->lastnameInput,           
                $this->hashedPassword);
                $statement->execute();
            }
        }

        public function validate_same_username(){
            $sql_same_username = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE   
            username = ?";
            if($statement_same_username =                              
            $this->connect->prepare($sql_same_username)){                             
                $this->usernameInput = input::get('user_val');
                $statement_same_username->bind_param("s",              
                $this->usernameInput);
                $statement_same_username->execute();
                $result = $statement_same_username->get_result();
                $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

                if($num_rows > 0){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
             }
         }

        public function login(){
            $sql_login = "SELECT username , password FROM users WHERE 
            username = ?";
            if($statement_login = $this->connect->prepare($sql_login)){

                $this->usernameInput = input::get('user_val');
                $this->passwordInput = input::get('password_val');

                $statement_login->bind_param("s",                     
                $this->usernameInput);
                $statement_login->execute();

                //get hashed password from database
                $statement_login->bind_result($username,$password);
                if(password_verify($this->passwordInput,$password)){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php 
    class session{

        public static function set($name,$value){
            return $name = $_SESSION[$value];
        }

        public static function get($name){
            return $_SESSION[$name];
        }

        public static function exists($name){
            if(isset($_SESSION[$name])){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

**input.php**

```
<?php 

    class input{

        public static function get($name){
            if(isset($_POST[$name])){
                return $_POST[$name];
            }else if(isset($_GET[$name])){
                return $_GET[$name];
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're using a `hashedpassword` on register but not hashing the password on login, it will never authenticate successfully.

Comment: @AmmoPT I've tried it but it doesn't matter though.

Comment: Update the code in your question with the new code you're using: 1) hash the password on authentication and 2) follow Ron's answer and use `password_val` instead of `user_val` in validation_login.php

Comment: @AmmoPT code updated, but still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you access `database.php?user_val=user&password_val=password` (replace `user` and `password` with valid, existent data) and on `login()` can you `var_dump($this->usernameInput)` and `var_dump($this->hashedPassword)`, after they've been defined.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I can't access it. I've tried it without hashing the password and it works. Any idea how to do it with hashing it?

Comment: According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) this will produce at least a 60 char length hash. Is your database storing the whole of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are getting the `user_val` to the password field at validation_login.php

`$this->password = input::get('user_val');`

from your code it should be 
`$this->password = input::get('password_val');`
i will start be changing to this line

edit to my initial answer:

you also can't use `password_hash()` (see return value section [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)) to check if the password equal, you need to use [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check if the password is equal in the login function

change your query to get the hashed password from the database and then compare it to the input password from the user with the `password_verify`

```
        $sql_login = "SELECT username , password FROM users WHERE 
        username = ? ";

        if(password_verify($this->passwordInput,$hashedPasswordFromDB)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

also check if you `password` column in the database in long enough to store the whole password length, and make sure you username is unique

Comment: It doesn't show any error, but it still doesn't validate properly when I try to login. I have inputted the correct username and password, but it still validates that i inputted the wrong username or password.

Comment: i would check if the input is what you expect in `login()` `echo  $this->usernameInput = input::get('user_val');
echo $this->passwordInput = input::get('password_val');` and  `echo $this->hashedPassword;`

Comment: I've checked it and the input is what i expected. But, seems like it doesn't work if I hashed my password. Any idea how to do proper login system with hashed password?

Comment: I've updated the `login()` function at `database.php`, please check it out.

Comment: you can get multiple columns on the same query with the `bind_param` function `$sql_login = "SELECT username , password FROM users WHERE 
        username = ? ";` and `$statement_login->bind_param("ss",                     
                $hashedPasswordFromDB);` and then user `$hashedPasswordFromDB` to validate the password

Comment: but it will cause error if number of the elements doesn't match number of bind variables, i've updated my code again, but seems like it doesn't work too.

Comment: ahhh, nevermind. i just forgot to fetch it so it doesn't work. thank you so much!

Comment: Perfect! don't forget to accept the answer so others may find it useful!